# How to check stack usage at Linux runtime?

Tags: c++, linux, stack

1. Is there any tool on Linux for checking the stack usage/size at runtime? I know we can do it by coding, but I would rather use tool than code.
2. GDB can be used to attach specific process, and `bt` command can display stack frames. Can the *value=(address of frame n - address of frame 1)* be considered as an approximate number of stack size?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sysconf()` subroutine to get stack usgae at run time. From the manual page of `sysconf()`

> sysconf - get configuration information at run time
>
> ```
> long sysconf(int name);
> ```
>
> At  compile time this is done by including  and/or
>   
>          and testing the value of certain macros. At run time, one can ask for numerical values using the  present  func‐
>          tion  sysconf().

use the various macros like `_SC_THREAD_ATTR_STACKADDR`, `_SC_THREAD_STACK_MIN` etc as specified in manual page of `sysconf()`.

Comment: see this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtsys.htm